# How do you undo setting an option in vim?

Tags: vim

I often call

```
:set spell
```

only to immediately call

```
:set nospell
```

once I've corrected the word I was unsure of.

I can make this faster by mapping both commands, but I'm looking for a more general way to speed this up. Is it possible to undo the last option :set?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Strictly speaking, no, you cannot undo setting a setting in Vim.

But boolean options like `'spell'` can be toggled with either one of

```
:set spell!
:set invspell
```

In interactive use there is generally no need to specifically `:set spell` or `:set nospell`. Toggling is more convenient and can be immediately "undone" with the [`@:`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/repeat.html#@%3a) command.

Non-boolean options can be undone by resetting them to their factory values – say, if you have messed up some setting and wish to revert. Example:

```
:set formatoptions&
```

A `&` appended to the option name resets it to its default value.

Comment: Thanks for the @: command, while not exactly what I was looking for it works perfectly for this use-case while still being quite general.

Answer (score 16):

I don’t know that you can *undo* the setting of an option, but in the case of an on / off option such as `spell`, you can toggle it with a `!` at the end of the option name:

```
:set spell!
```

Comment: This combined with the [command-line history](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Using_command-line_history) should be very fast to perform.

Comment: @RussellSilva Yes indeed. I also have `nnoremap ; :` and `nnoremap : ;` in my .vimrc, so to repeat this command could be as simple as ;<up><cr>.